# Adding a motion effect to a layers's mask

Tags: ios

I have a UILabel (shineLabel) in gold that I'm looking to highlight when the user tilts the device. Think iOS 6's Music.app volume knobs but on text, where a mask is required.

Currently the mask occupies the views' layer.mask property. When I animate this layer without the motion control, it works exactly as expected. The highlight passes over the text and is masked by the shape of the characters.

Now I'm trying to implement iOS 7's addMotionEffect:as per [these instructions](http://www.redwindsoftware.com/blog/post/2013/10/05/UIMotionEffects-for-Dummies.aspx?utm_source=iOS+Dev+Weekly&utm_campaign=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_115&utm_medium=email) but not having any luck animating just the mask. My code for the layer with the mask:

```
self.shineLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:28];
self.shineLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.shineLabel.text = @"Hello";

[self addSubview:self.shineLabel];

// Create the mask and assign it to the shineLabel's layer.mask property
CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];

maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0] CGColor];
maskLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlight.png"] CGImage];

maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(-self.journalLabelTitle.frame.size.width - 40, 0.0f, self.shineLabel.frame.size.width * 2, self.shineLabel.frame.size.height);

self.shineLabel.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

And code to animate and react to device's motion:

```
// Set horizontal effect
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect =
[[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
 initWithKeyPath:@"layer.mask.position.x"
 type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-40.0f);
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(40.0f);

// Add effect to your view
[self.shineLabel addMotionEffect:horizontalMotionEffect];
```

If I change initWithKeyPath:"layer.mask.position.x" to "layer.position.x" I can move the views' layer, but it seems if I try to move just the layer.mask I can't.

Can anyone help me figure this out please?

Comment: Solution: use Facebook shimmer. https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer